# Critical section algorithm to satisfy progress of processes by comparing two algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, deadlock, critical-section

Here is two algorithm for critical section. The first one is not satisfying progressive requirement and second on is the solution. I think there is a problem with second one but my lecturer did not admit it. We need to somehow assign turn to new value after each process is entering the reminder section? Is it right?

```
boolean flag[2];
initially flag [0] = flag [1] = false.
flag [i] = true 
//Pi ready to enter its critical section
//Process Pi
do {
   flag[i] = true;
   while (flag[j]) ;
   critical section
   flag [i] = false;
   remainder section
} while ( … );
```

it satisfy mutual exclusion but not progress and now by changing it to this we meet the need for progressive:

```
int turn;
boolean flag[2];
initially flag [0] = flag [1] = false, turn = i (or j)
Process Pi
do {
   flag [i] = true;
   turn = j;
   while (flag [j] and turn = j) ;
   critical section
   flag [i] = false;
remainder section
while(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

The second algorithm is correct as written.

The `turn` variable is relevant only during the time that *both* processes are waiting for each other's flags.

There is no need to reset `turn` upon exiting the critical section, because it will be reset before its value is tested again -- by the next process that tries to enter the critical section.